# the job exceeded end severity (ENDSEV job attribute)

Tags: network-printer, ibm-midrange

one of our clients recently purchased a new printer. This printer is a slightly different model from what it is replacing, however is only an upgraded model (T640 to T644) - The printer can be pinged with the STRPRTWTR command, but the writer ends within a minute or two saying that it ended abnormally with an error code of 20, "The job exceeded end severity (ENDSEV job attribute".

We normally do not handle printers on non windows/mac machines, however I am hoping to be able to help this customer out. Any advice on what information I can relay to him to possibly help?

Answer (score 1):

1. The writer job log should have more information.  Have the IBM admin look at the job logs; maybe WRKOUTQ QEZJOBLOG.
2. There are several ways to configure a printer on IBM i.  Support document [22393632](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1455975a3bf2ac71e862569f9006ba227) has a synopsis.  If the printer is configured as *LAN 3812 PJL, double check the port number in the device description (WRKDEVD)
3. Check that the spooled file being printed is allowed by the device description.  For instance, a *AFPDS spooled file can't be printed on a *SCS device.

Answer (score 1):

I have set up clients with a similar mix of Lexmark printers and they have switched/replaced/upgraded them interchangeably without issue simply by matching the previous ip address.

The printers are configured as `DEVCLS(*LAN) TYPE(3812) MODEL(1) LANATTACH(*IP) PORT(9100) TRANSFORM(*YES) MFRTYPMDL(*LEXOPTRAT) SYSDRVPGM(*IBMPJLDRV)`.

To determine the exact cause we would need more information from the printer job log as Buck indicated.

You may be able to find the job logs with the command `WRKJOBLOG JOBLOGSTT(*SPOOLED) PERIOD((*AVAIL *BEGIN)) JOB(printername)`.